# Python: good way to pass variable to multiple function calls

Tags: python, function, arguments, global-variables

Need a help with the next situation. I want to implement debug mode in my script through printing small completion report in functions with command executed name and ellapsed time like:

```
def cmd_exec(cmd):
    if isDebug:
        commandStart = datetime.datetime.now()
        print commandStart
        print cmd
    ...
    ... exucuting commands
    ...
    if isDebug:
        print datetime.datetime.now() - command_start
    return

def main():
    ...
    if args.debug:
        isDebug = True
    ...
    cmd_exec(cmd1)
    ...
    cmd_exec(cmd2)
    ...
```

How can isDebug variable be simply passed to functions?
Should I use "global isDebug"?

Because

```
    ...
    cmd_exec(cmd1, isDebug)
    ...
    cmd_exec(cmd2, isDebug)
    ...
```

looks pretty bad. Please help me find more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a module to create variables that are shared. This is better than a global because it only affects code that is specifically looking for the variable, it doesn't pollute the global namespace. It also lets you define something without your main module needing to know about it.

This works because modules are shared objects in Python. Every `import` gets back a reference to the same object, and modifications to the contents of that module get shared immediately, just like a global would.

my_debug.py:

```
isDebug = false
```

main.py:

```
import my_debug

def cmd_exec(cmd):
    if my_debug.isDebug:
        # ...

def main():
    # ...
    if args.debug:
        my_debug.isDebug = True
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. The problem is that I switch mode frequently. And it's more convenient to swich debug mode only by adding '-d' option at the starting of the script

Comment: @VadimK I'm not sure what the objection is. The bits of code I present here were copied directly from your question.

Comment: Yes, I mean that to turn on/off debug mode i will need to edit _my_debug.py_ file every time

Comment: @VadimK no, that's not true at all - look at my example!

Comment: @VadimK thanks for the accept. I realized that I didn't explain my answer thoroughly, so I've added a bit to it.

Answer (score 2):

`isDebug` is state that applies to the application of a function `cmd_exec`. Sounds like a use-case for a class to me.

```
class CommandExecutor(object):

    def __init__(self, debug):
        self.debug = debug

    def execute(self, cmd):
        if self.debug:
            commandStart = datetime.datetime.now()
            print commandStart
            print cmd
        ...
        ... executing commands
        ...
        if self.debug:
            print datetime.datetime.now() - command_start

def main(args):
    ce = CommandExecutor(args.debug)
    ce.execute(cmd1)
    ce.execute(cmd2)
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Can you explain one more thing; what if _cmd_exec_ function called not only from _main_ but also from many other functions? Does it mean that I will be obliged to operate with a class instance instead of one variable

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in `__debug__` variable that could be useful.

```
if __debug__:
    print 'information...'
```

When you run your program as `python test.py`, `__debug__` is `True`. If you run it as `python -O test.py`, it will be `False`.

Another option which I do in my projects is set a global `DEBUG` var at the beginning of the file, after importing:

```
DEBUG = True
```

You can then reference this `DEBUG` var in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for this, I would use partials/currying, basically pre-filling a variable.

```
import sys
from functools import partial
import datetime

def _cmd_exec(cmd, isDebug=False):
    if isDebug:
        command_start = datetime.datetime.now()
        print command_start
        print cmd

    else:
        print 'isDebug is false' + cmd

    if isDebug:
        print datetime.datetime.now() - command_start
    return

#default, keeping it as is...
cmd_exec = _cmd_exec

#switch to debug
def debug_on():
    global cmd_exec

    #pre-apply the isDebug optional param
    cmd_exec = partial(_cmd_exec, isDebug=True)


def main():
    if "-d" in sys.argv:
        debug_on()

    cmd_exec("cmd1")
    cmd_exec("cmd2")

main()
```

In this case, I check for `-d` on the command line to turn on debug mode and I do pre-populate isDebug on the function call by creating a new function with `isDebug = True`.

I think even other modules will see this modified cmd_exec, because I replaced the function at the module level.

output:

**jluc@explore$ py test_so64.py**
`isDebug is falsecmd1
isDebug is falsecmd2`

**jluc@explore$ py test_so64.py -d**
`2016-10-13 17:00:33.523016
cmd1
0:00:00.000682
2016-10-13 17:00:33.523715
cmd2
0:00:00.000009`